# React native - can't horizontally center my scroll view

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to center my autocomplete component positioned as absolute, but it doesn't work as i want :(

can you help me to solve my problem if possible ?

[This is the screenshot of my result at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDe1t.png)

And this is my component code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'material-bread';

const styles = {
    container: {
        backgroundColor:"#fff",
        width:300,
        position:'absolute',
        elevation:150,
        zIndex:150,
        borderRadius:30,
        flex:10,
        left:0,
        right:0,
        top:0
    },

    content: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        flex: 1,
        paddingLeft: 10, //if you need separation.
        color:"#152c5b",
        textAlign:'left'
    },

    subcontent: {
        height:30,
        width:'100%',
        textAlign:'left'
    },

    text: {
        color:'#152c5b',
    },

    bold: {
        fontWeight:'bold',
    },

    ios_fix: {
        marginTop:138,
        left:40
    }
}

export default class Autocomplete_component extends Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data : []
        }

        this.componentDidUpdate = (pPrevProps, pPrevState) => {

            
            if(this.props.data.length == 0 && this.state.data.length > 0)
                this.setState({data : []});
            else
            {
                if(this.props.data.length > 0 && (this.state.data.length == 0 || this.props.data != this.state.data))
                    this.setState({data: this.props.data})
            }

            
        }
        
    }


    render() {
            {
              if(this.state.data.length > 0){
                return (<View style={[styles.container, Platform.OS === 'ios' && styles.ios_fix]}>
                    {this.state.data.map((lData, lI) => {
                        
                        return(<View style={styles.content} key={lI.toString()}>
                                   <View style={styles.subcontent}>

                                   <Button key={lI} type="text" textColor={'#152c5b'} style={{textAlign:'left', width:'100%', justifyContent: "flex-start"}}
                                           onPress={() => {this.props.onItemSelect(lData)}}>

                                        <Text style={{color:'#152c5b', textAlign:'left'}}>
                                            <Text key='test' style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>
                                                {lData.word.substring(0, lData.word.indexOf(this.props.query))}{this.props.query}
                                            </Text>
                                            {lData.word.slice(this.props.query.length)}
                                            </Text>
                                    </Button>

                                   </View>
                               </View>
                        )

                    })
                    }
                </View>)
              }else
                return null;
            }        
    }
}
```

i think the problem is in the container style, but i can't find solution.

Thank for your help

Comment: Why would you position the view as absolute? Any valid reason for that?

Comment: Yes because, else, my compononent go under my search component

Comment: @Luffydev But where's the `ScrollView` in your question ?

Comment: Ok, then, you should manipule your container's ```top``` and ```left``` properties, they will work as margins so ```top``` adds some pixels from the top of your screen, and ```left``` does the same but from left. Let me know if it worked. In example there are ```top: 0, left: 0``` so the view will be at the top left corner.